# MySQL access denied for user to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to my phpMyAdmin database called "db", but I am getting the following error:

> username@servername:~$ mysql -u username -p password
>
> Enter password: *(I enter my password)*
>
> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to
>   database 'password'

I am pretty sure that my username and password are correct, and that I have the privileges to access the database. What's confusing me is this part:

> database 'password'

since that's not the name of my database. The **db.php** file looks like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'uni_',
];
```

Comment: `-ppassword`, without space. In your case you are trying to connect to database "password" and assume that you will input password from keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're messing up the `mysql` command. You're connecting to a database called `password` and not giving the actually password. You should do this:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword
```

or this:

```
mysql -u username --password=password
```

The reason for this is that if a space follows the option letter, the program has no way to tell whether a following argument is supposed to be the password value or some other kind of argument.

Check it out [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/command-line-options.html).